# custom fields for address are not being saved?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I added some custom fields for address for in a twig template which extends from

```
@Storefront/storefront/component/address/address-form.html.twig
```

when i submit the form from the /checkout/register page, the custom fields are not saved.

In the Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterRoute.php file, when data mapping is done for address, only the fields below are mapped:

```
private function mapAddressData(DataBag $addressData): array
{
    $mappedData = $addressData->only(
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'salutationId',
        'street',
        'zipcode',
        'city',
        'company',
        'department',
        'countryStateId',
        'countryId',
        'additionalAddressLine1',
        'additionalAddressLine2',
        'phoneNumber'
    );

    if (isset($mappedData['countryStateId']) && $mappedData['countryStateId'] === '') {
        $mappedData['countryStateId'] = null;
    }

    return $mappedData;
}
```

How can i save custom fields for an address when developing an app? is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

There's [this repository](https://github.com/vanWittlaer/blog-example-two) (not mine) with an example on how to add additional inputs to the storefront and how to map them to the payload when persisting the address. Basically you subscribe to the corresponding `CustomerEvents`, take the user inputs and enrich the payload.

Comment: can i do that with an app? i know i can subscribe to events from a plugin, not an app

Comment: As of today apps aren't yet capable to do what has been done with this plugin